# Remove numbers that aren't within square brackets in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a generated a series of arrays in JavaScript but need to remove all numbers that are outside of square brackets.

Now I'm aware I need to use some form of Regex but I'm not sure how to use it in this instance.

Here's a sample of my arrays:

1[1,0.031410759078128],2[2,0.062790519529313],3[3,0.094108313318514],4[4,0.1253332335643],5[5,0.15643446504023]

etc.

How can I remove all the numbers that aren't in square brackets?

Comment: Do you want to keep the commas between? Are there ever brackets inside brackets? Is the desired output [1,0.031410759078128],[2,0.062790519529313],[3,0.094108313318514],[4,0.1253332335643],[5,0.15643446504023]? I am imagining you could write a function to do this that tracks a state of whether or not you are inside brackets as you iterate through the string.

Comment: You are generating the arrays? If so, then it should be done correctly, this looks like a string set, rather than an array. An array you can extract via the index of the array, and that would be it. Can you clarify more?

Comment: I'm guessing the reason you got a down vote was that you haven't shown that you tried anything first.

Comment: I want to preserve commas, there are no brackets within brackets, and that is my desired output

Comment: I'm guessing the reason you got a down vote was that you haven't shown the desired output. Can there be multiple numbers outside the brackets, such as `n,m[x]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a [zero-width lookahead assertion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion). The Regex string below will select all numbers in sequence that come directly before a '['.

```
/([0-9]+)(?=\[)+/g
```

Rexexr.com is a great resource. http://regexr.com/3e63k

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for, and great link too I think I'll bookmark it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var stripNumsOutside = function(s) {
    var result = "";
    var insideBrackets = false;
    var curChar;
    for (var i = 0;
        (i < s.length); i++) {
        curChar = s[i];
        if (curChar == "[") {
            insideBrackets = true;
        }
        if ((insideBrackets) || (curChar == ",")) {
            result += curChar;
        };
        if (curChar == "]") {
            insideBrackets = false;
        };
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(stripNumsOutside("1[1,0.031410759078128],2[2,0.062790519529313],3[3,0.094108313318514],4[4,0.1253332335643],5[5,0.15643446504023]"));
```

Comment: It's often best to add a narrative to your answer, and in this case also note why you think regexp won't work or isn't best.

Comment: @torazaburo fair enough. I was working on this before regexp was up (see comment abovee), and wanted to show an alternative. I think the regexp is fine and probably is better. I thought this might be easier to follow or illustrate a different way of thinking about it.